# The type or method has 3 generic parameter(s), but 2 generic argument(s) were provided

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following working code:

```
Context context = new Context(_options);

Expression<Func<Context.Person, Context.Address>> e1 = x => x.Address;
Expression<Func<Context.Address, Context.Country>> e2 = x => x.Country;

IIncludableQueryable<Context.Person, Context.Address> a = context.Persons.Include(e1);
IIncludableQueryable<Context.Person, Context.Country> b = a.ThenInclude(e2);

List<Context.Person> result = context.Persons.Include(e1).ThenInclude(e2).ToList();
```

Where [Include](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/78476005b30ff201d4523d24da090ce6c84fb248/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2227) and [ThenInclude](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/78476005b30ff201d4523d24da090ce6c84fb248/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2291) are Entity Framework Core extension methods.

In my code I will need to use generic types so I am using reflection:

```
IQueryable<Context.Person> persons = context.Persons;

MethodInfo include = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Include" && x.GetParameters().Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()).SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));

MethodInfo thenInclude = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "ThenInclude" && x.GetParameters().Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()).SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IIncludableQueryable<,>), typeof(Expression<>) }));

Expression<Func<Context.Person, Context.Address>> l1 = x => x.Address;

Expression<Func<Context.Address, Context.Country>> l2 = x => x.Country;


try {

  MethodInfo includeInfo = include.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Context.Person), l1.ReturnType);

  IIncludableQueryable<Context.Person, Context.Address> r1 = (IIncludableQueryable<Context.Person, Context.Address>)includeInfo.Invoke(null, new Object[] { persons, l1 });

  MethodInfo thenIncludeInfo = thenInclude.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Context.Address), l2.ReturnType);

  IIncludableQueryable<Context.Address, Context.Country> r2 = (IIncludableQueryable<Context.Address, Context.Country>)thenIncludeInfo.Invoke(null, new Object[] { r1, l2 });

  var r = r2.AsQueryable();

} catch (Exception ex) { }
```

But on this code line:

```
MethodInfo thenIncludeInfo = thenInclude.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Context.Address), l2.ReturnType);
```

I get the following error:

```
The type or method has 3 generic parameter(s), but 2 generic argument(s) were provided. A generic argument must be provided for each generic parameter.
```

I can understand the error by looking at ThenInclude definition but I am not sure how to solve it ...

Comment: The signature of `ThenInclude` expects 3 generic parameters (`<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>`) but you're only passing 2.

Comment: @haim770 I tried to pass 3 using "MethodInfo thenIncludeInfo = thenInclude.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Context.Person), typeof(Context.Address), l2.ReturnType);" but then I get the error "Object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions+IncludableQuer‌​yable2[Person,Address]' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable2[Person,System.Collec‌​tions.Generic.ICollection`1[Address]]'.". Do you know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the message suggests, `ThenInclude` expects 3 type parameters: `TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty`. From your code, it would seem this would work:

```
MethodInfo thenIncludeInfo = thenInclude.MakeGenericMethod(
    typeof(Context.Person), typeof(Context.Address), l2.ReturnType);
```

Comment: The first generic argument is `TEntity` which (as far as I can infer from the OP's code) is `Person`. The 2nd argument is `TPreviousProperty` which is the type of the property passed to the first `Include()` (`Address` in this case).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now I get the error "Object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions+IncludableQueryable`2[Person,Address]' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable`2[Person,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Address]]'." ... Not sure why ... Do you know?